# How do I conduct referencial integrity using foreign key constraints in netbeans sql?

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I am trying to write sql code in netbeans. 
I have two tables:

```
Create table building(
        building_name varchar(10) not null primary key,
        building_location varchar(20),
        building_room_number integer);

Insert into building values('Building A', 'Location A',34);
Insert into building values('Building B','Location B',45);
Insert into building values('Building C', 'Location C',40);

Create table room(
        room_number integer primary key,
        building_name varchar(10));

Insert into room values(1, 'Building A');
Insert into room values(2, 'Building B');
Insert into room values(3,  'Building C');
```

Then I want to create foreign key to conduct referential integrity.

```
ALTER TABLE room
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_room
FOREIGN KEY (building_name) REFERENCES building(building_name)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Netbeans kept giving me this error

```
  [Exception, Error code 905, SQLState 42000] ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

I m not sure what's wrong with my syntax. How should I write foreign key constrains in netbeans sql?

Thank you for your help><

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct in MySQL.

The error log you posted looks like an Oracle log. Are you sure you are executing the `ALTER` statement in and incorrect Netbeans tab?